# Semistable points of an open subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $X$ be a quasiprojective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $G$ a reductive group acting on $X$. Let us moreover assume to have a very ample line bundle $L$ over $X$ which admits a $G$ linearization. Given $U \subseteq X$ an open $G$-stable subvariety, we can consider the restricted line bundle $L|_U$ which admits the induced $G$ linearization.

In general is it true that $X^{ss} \cap U=U^{ss}$ (by which I'm denoting the semistable points with respect to the linearization induced on $X$ and $U$ respectively)? Are there any conditions on $U$ for which this happens to be true? I'd be particularly interested in the case of $X$ projective.

By looking at the general definition of $$X^{ss}(L)=\{x \in X  \ \ \text{s.t}\ \ \exists \sigma \in H^0(X,L^{n})^G \ \text{s.t} \  \sigma(x) \neq 0\}  $$
I was able only to get the standard inclusion $X^{ss} \cap U \subseteq U^{ss}$ but not more.